# Error : An expression tree may not contain a dynamic operation

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, entity-framework, sql-like

I'm trying to make a `where ... like ...` operation via Entity Framework. But, I've got this error :

> An expression tree may not contain a dynamic operation.

on this code :

```
var model =_db.Postes.Where(x => SqlFunctions.PatIndex("%" + ViewBag.Recherche + "%", x.nomPoste) > 0);
```

How do I to fix that, please ?

Comment: try assigning ViewBag.Recherche to a variable and using that in your query.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is ViewBag is a dynamic type and the type of `Recherche` cannot be determined at compilation time of the page or view (assuming you're using Razor). An explicit cast of ViewBag.Recherche to its type is enough for the compiler to continue and you shouldn't see the problem anymore.

Answer (score 0):

just add ViewBag.Recherche to a variable and use it inside query

```
var re =  ViewBag.Recherche;

var model =_db.Postes.Where(x => SqlFunctions.PatIndex("%" + re + "%", x.nomPoste) > 0);
```